# Firestore query gets called more than once Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using FireStore in swift to access data.
I was using compounded query to access the needed values, and noticed that the query happens more than once sometimes, creating duplicates in the array created.

This is the query I have.

```
db.collection("friendlist")
  .document(UID)
  .collection("friends")
  .whereField("user", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: keyword)
  .whereField("user", isLessThan: upperBound)
  .getDocuments()
```

Sometimes this code works fine but other times it gets called more than once, even getting called three times occassionally

is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: where in your code did you call this? which lifecycle event?

Comment: It is called in searchBarTextDidChange. But I have checked that searchBarTextDidChange itself does not get called more than once

Comment: The code you showed will only get the documents once. But you don't show how you're calling it, nor what you do with the results, which is likely where the problem comes from. Please edit your question to show the [minimum complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (click the link, it's quite useful).